# Consulta SQL utilizando PgAdmin4

Tags: postgresql, sql, pgadmin

Dadas las siguientes tablas:

```
FACTURAS (Nrofactura, Cliente, Fecha)

DETALLES (Nrofactura, Renglón, Articulo, Cantidad, Preciouni)
```

Se pide hallar la fecha en la que más se facturó, intenté hacerlo, este es el código que llevo:

```
SELECT fecha,  SUM(cantidad*preciouni) AS totales
FROM facturas, detalles
WHERE facturas.nrofactura=detalles.nrofactura
GROUP BY fecha
```

Pero lo que me da, son las fechas con su respectivo dinero recaudado, la respuesta debería ser una sola fila con el máximo dinero recaudado en cierta fecha. Sé que debería usar una clausula MAX o algo así pero no sé dónde colocarla, me gustaría que la respuesta se diera en 1 solo select y lo más corta posible.

Comment: Lectura recomedada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Comment: Puedes utilizar el max en el select max(fecha)

Comment: no podes ser mas especifico?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

prueba con esto:

```
select fecha,sum(cantidad * preciouni) as total
from facturas f join detalles d on f.nrofactura=d.nrofactura
group by fecha
order by sum(cantidad * preciouni) desc
limit 1
```

Debería devolverte solo una tupla, con la fecha y el total más alto, por ejemplo:

fecha                  total
2020-02-03 00:00:00    9200.0000